# Octave, plotting function with one changing variable on two places

Tags: plot, octave

I am new in Octave but I would like to plot a function that has a same changing variable on two places.

The function looks like `x/(x+2)`.

When one x changes the other one should have the same values as the other one.

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`fplot`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Two_002ddimensional-Function-Plotting.html)

```
>> fplot(@(x) x ./ (x + 2), limits);
```

`limits` is a vector of 2 elements containing the limits of `x` that you would like to plot the function between.